# Reset lightning:input textbox Field Value to Null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am trying to create a button which will update a field value to null (RESET it). However, it's not working and not even giving any error. So when I click on the button, nothing happens.

lc.cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="myObj" type="Account" default="{'SObject':'Account'}"/>
<lightning:input type="text" name="accountPhn" label="Enter Account Phone" value="{!v.myObj.Name}"/>
<lightning:button label="Reset" onclick="{!c.resetMe}"/>
```

lc.js:

```
resetMe : function(component, event, helper) {
        //alert("Called");
        component.set("v.accountPhn","");
    }
```

Appreciate help around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change 2nd line with below code. It will work.

```
    <aura:attribute name="accountPhn" type="String" default="{!v.myObj.Name}"/>
```

Comment: Hello Dhanik,

I need input text box only... hence need to nulify those itself... hope you understand

Comment: Please check with this <aura:attribute name="accountPhn" type="String" default="{!v.myObj.Name}"/>
<lightning:input type="text" name="text" label="Enter Account Phone" value="{!v.accountPhn}"/>

Comment: Worked great... thanks Dhanik

Answer (score 0):

Component.get() and Component.set() works on the attributes defined. Update your component with below, it should be fine.

```
<aura:attribute name="accountPhn" type="String"/>
<lightning:input type="text" name="accountPh" label="Enter Account Phone" value=" 
{!v.accountPhn}"/>
<lightning:button label="Reset" onclick="{!c.resetMe}"/>
```

Read more about [Component.get() and Component.set()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm)

Comment: I tried... still doesn;t work, same thing, nothing happens... Does below have any significance:

```
<aura:attribute name="accountPhn" type="String"/>
<lightning:input type="text" name="accountPh" label="Enter Account Phone" value=" 
{!v.accountPhn}"/>
```

as I want to nulify the lightning:input type="text"

Comment: You can try printing the values using console.log and check the values before it is set to blank , and after it is set to blank and check its not printing undefined. You need to tie the value of <lightning:input> to an attribute of the component and manipulate it using component.set()